# Looking for Search Algorithm Name

Tags: algorithm, search

I assume there is a name for what I describe here.

Basically, if I search for "word1 word2 word3" (without quotes) and I have this array:

```
 ["word1 word2",
 "word1 word2 word3",
 "word3 word2 word1",
 "word2 word3 word1",
 "word1 word3 word2 word4",
 "word1 word4 word3",
 "word4 word1 word2 word3"]
```

It should return these found results:

```
word1 word2 word3
word3 word2 word1
word2 word3 word1
word1 word3 word2 word4
word4 word1 word2 word3
```

Is there any name for such an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description would be:

"Search for a all strings that contain all permutations of the following words". So maybe it should be called "Permutation Search": http://www.keyworddiscovery.com/feature-permutation-search.html

Answer (score 0):

If you also allow `word1 word4 word2 word3` to be returned it would be called 'keyword based search' or 'full text search' with the limitation that the search text should contain all keywords (and not only a subset).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is basically

```
Search : search-set{1,2,3}

In :
sample-space-set{
 set{1,2,3}
 set{1,2,3,4}
 set{2,3,4,5}
}

Result:
result-set{
 set{1,2,3}
 set{1,2,3,4} 
}
```

Which could be put more concisely as
Find all the result-set from the sample-space-set where 'search-set is a subset'.

So basically, name of algorithm could be
**'find all the mother-of-subsets'**

(I really dont know what is the reverse of subset relationship. If you know that do let us know all.)